# Request-Promise Library Error when using socks5:- RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js

Error: RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND socks5://1.1.1.1:1000

Used NodeJS Modules:

request-promise
socks-proxy-agent

So, I'm sure that my code is right and followed lot of examples but when it runs, it output this error. What I can think of is that request-promise trying connect to socks5 host instead of the specified request URL.

Code is below,

```js
async function main() {

  const proxy = "socks5://"+req.body.ip+":"+req.body.port

  // Connection Info
  const connection_info = {
    host: proxy,
    userId: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }

  //Initialize Connection + Start Agent
  const agent = new SocksProxyAgent(connection_info);

  //Request using request-promise library
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://endpoint.goes.here',
    agent: agent,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': req.body.useragent
    },
    body: {
      id: "1"
    },
    json: true
  }
  return await rp(options)
}

let response = main(); // Call Async Function, Save Response Object
var headers = response.headers;
var body = response.body;
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to produce different error by changing keys on connection object as follows,

```
const connection_info = {
//host: core_proxy,
protocol:"socks5:",
host:req.body.ip,
port:req.body.port,
username: req.body.username,
password: req.body.password
```

}

New error is  ***Error: Proxy connection timed out***

**UPDATE:**

I have set timeout to 20000, but it still gives same error.

I guess I might have to try with another proxy.

**UPDATE:**

Tried with another proxy, same error.

I can't think of what else is missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using an another socks5 library called socks5-https-client. And, I still don't know what's the exact issue with other library.

I leave it to experts to figure-out.